# global.css.webpack and node modules errors

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, next.js

./styles/globals.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!../../node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].oneOf[12].use[2]!../../node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].oneOf[12].use[3]!./styles/globals.css
Error: Cannot find module '@tailwindcss/forms'
Require stack:

- D:\novel\apps\web\tailwind.config.js

unable to run novel repository in next js project getting following error